# Command line doesn't refresh immidately after carriage return

Tags: raspbian, carriage-return

I have a code which does something similar to this one.

```
while(1){
      printf("Telegrams received %d\r",telegrams); //notice \r
      telegrams++;
      sleep(); // for 0.2s
}
```

The output from this is one line in a command line which is being updated. However my problem is, that the line isn't updated after every telegram, but only after every 17... (which takes something like 3 seconds).
Is there any way, how to make this work to change every 0.2 seconds?
(when I press enter, there is displayed everything...)

I'm running this on raspberry pi with raspbian.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer - I need to use `fflush(stdout)` after every printf.